# How to use same message header id in queue?

Tags: activemq-classic

I want to use the Message Header ID generated in Queue 1 to Queue 2. 
Can you please tell me how to achieve this in ActiveMQ?

*Scenario:*

1. Queue 1 message was not processed by ESB bus due to some failure
2. We will be using Queue 2 to post the message again after fixing it with 
   the same Message Header ID created in Queue 1

*Queue 1 (Process):* 
Message Header ID : ID:XYZ-1234-1555664319032-4:2:1:1:1

*Queue 2 (Re-process):* 
Message Header ID : ID:XYZ-1234-1555664319032-4:2:1:1:1

Many Thanks, 
Samuel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveMQ itself assigns the message IDs. It's not something which can be done from a client application. You'll need to use a different message header or property for your application-specific ID.

Comment: Justin, That really useful for me. I am using a different header to handle that situation.